# Cannot use c++ dll in vb.net project

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, pinvoke

I want to call a c++ function from my vb.net project and i'm trying to create a dll to do so.I've never tried it before so according to the guides i read i created a dll.dll(using C++ in Visual Studio) with a dll.def file and i tried linking it to my VB project. Athough i can build it without any error it crushes and i get

'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException'

Additional information: PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.

My code is this:

dll.h

```
#define WDL_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" WDL_API int __stdcall wdl(void);
```

dll.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dll.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


char var[] = {"a"};
extern "C" WDL_API int __stdcall wdl(void)
{
    int i, len1 = sizeof(var);
    char sName[100], sAns[10];
    FILE *ptr;
    errno_t errorCode = fopen_s(&ptr, ".\\file", "wb");
    for (i = 0; i<len1 - 1; i++)
        fprintf(ptr, "%c", var[i]);
    fclose(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

dll.def

```
LIBRARY dll

EXPORTS
wdl @1
```

vbproject

```
Module Module1
    Public Declare Auto Function wdl _
        Lib "dll.dll" Alias "wdl" ()

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("inside vb.net")
        wdl()
    End Sub

End Module
```

The code seems to make sense but i can't find out if i am missing something or there are mistakes of some kind.Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the return type and so VB assumes that it is a variant. You don't want that. It is a C `int`, or VB `Integer`. Code it like this:

```
Public Declare Auto Function wdl Lib "dll.dll" Alias "wdl" () As Integer
```

That said, pinvoke is to be preferred over `Declare` these days so I would write it like this:

```
<DllImport("dll.dll")> _
Public Shared Function wdl() As Integer
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all.When i add the As Integer i get System.DllNotFoundException which i don't understand since I have added the dll to the project(project->add existing item).
As for using DllImport,do you mean i should just replace the "Public Declare...As Integer" line with "<DllImport("dll.dll")> _
Public Shared Function wdl() As Integer" ?

Comment: Don't add the DLL to the project. Just make sure that the DLL is in the same directory as the executable. Let's get it working with `Declare` before we switch to pinvoke.

Comment: The directory was the problem!I guess adding it wasn't the way to go as you said.It's working now.Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good. By the way, excellent question. Very clean and simple. If only they were all like that!!

Comment: They're both p/invoke - the first is just the legacy VB syntax - it produces very similar IL to the second.